# Always use a designated Initializer

Tags: objective-c

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW55 states that there shall be one designed initializer, and that the other initializers shall call the designed initializer.

1.
What is the main reason for this? I mean, each secondary initializer could do the [super init] call themselves (and thereby of cause become designed initializers).

2.
A follow up question:
Will every call between secondaries and the designed initializer generate a message passing step, or is there any way for the compiler to avoid that? As the initializers are after all in the same file... If a message passing step is introduced, I think that question 1 is even more relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main reasons for having a designated initializer are simplicity and subclassing. If you have many initializers, each one has to do all of the work, meaning you will have to duplicate your initialization code into each of them. With all secondary initializers calling the same designated initializer, most of the initialization code can go into one place, and each of the others only has to make small changes.

For subclassing, consider the case of class A, which has many initializers, and class B, which is a subclass of A. If A has a designated initializer, then B only has to override that one method in order to catch every initialization. But if A's initializers don't call a single method, then B has to override each one, or it will not always get a chance to initialize its objects.

Yes, there will be a message sent when you call the designated initializer. While the compiler *could* call the method directly, it won't because of the dynamic nature of the language, in combination with the possibilities of subclassing. In the example above, if A uses a designated initializer but doesn't send a message, then B's designated initializer still won't be called. Passing the message allows the runtime to find the first class with that method. Also, since the language is dynamic, there is a chance that the designated initializer's address will be changed at runtime, either by loading a category which redefines it, or by using runtime calls to change it directly.