# Recommended instance variables initialization place for Cocoa Touch classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm feeling very stupid, but...what is ***the right way*** to init instance variables in custom types, derived from Cocoa Touch UI classes?

Say I have type, derived from `UIViewController`, let it be `TRUIController`.
I defined an ivar as follows:

```
@implementation TRUIController
{
    NSNumberFormatter *_numberFormatter;
}
@end
```

And where should I put `_numberFormatter` initialization code, if I want it to be executed before any UI methods like `viewDidLoad`, etc?

In other languages I would create `constructor`, call `base` `constructor` and then init my ivars.
But that simply does not work in `objective-c` and `Cocoa Touch`.

In case described above,
If I write

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibBundleOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self)
    {
        //init ivars
    }
    return self;
}
```

It won't work, I'll try other `initWithBlaBla` methods, and finally find `init`, which is ***actually called***, in that case - `initWithCoder:`

Now, let's say I have class, derived from UITableViewCell. Again, need to init `NSNumberFormatter` ivar. Why can't I just override `init:`, call `super` and init my ivars?

What's the idea behind this strange design decision not to have single common initialization method for all types?

Is it the only way to initialize ivars in derived types? Every time do some research to figure out what method to override this time?

Have I missed something? Because it feels extremely stupid/unintuitive/error-prone

Comment: Hm. "Why can't I just override init:, call super and init my ivars?" - you **just can.**

Comment: No, I cannot. init is not called for (for example) UIViewController subclass (storyboards)

Comment: There's no such method as `init:`. You probably want to try `init`.

Comment: Tried init (sorry, mistyped in comment, now corrected). init method is not called for UIViewController subclass in storyboard app. Double checked again. Same for UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: I see. Then, why don't you override one of the initializers that are actually called?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out here - what's the common method which is called for every type, i can override, and why there is no one (if so)

Comment: the initializer that is always called is the **designed** one in Cocoa. Every class has his own, declared in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do so overriding the designated initializer.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/FrameworkImpl.html)

> A designated initializer is an init method of a class that invokes an
>   init method of the superclass. (Other initializers invoke the init
>   methods defined by the class.) Every public class should have one or
>   more designated initializers. As examples of designated initializers
>   there is NSView’s initWithFrame: and NSResponder’s init method. Where
>   init methods are not meant to be overridden, as is the case with
>   NSString and other abstract classes fronting class clusters, the
>   subclass is expected to implement its own.
>
> Designated initializers should be clearly identified because this
>   information is important to those who want to subclass your class. **A
>   subclass can just override the designated initializer and all other
>   initializers will work as designed.**
>
> When you implement a class of a framework, you often have to implement
>   its archiving methods as well: initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:. Be
>   careful not to do things in the initialization code path that doesn’t
>   happen when the object is unarchived. A good way to achieve this is to
>   call a common routine from your designated initializers and
>   initWithCoder: (which is a designated initializer itself) if your
>   class implements archiving.

Read the documentation for finding out which initializer is the designated one and override it.

According to the [documentation of UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `initWithNibName:bundle:` is the designated initializer for this class is so you should override that one, **but** if you are not programmatically instantiating your class (e.g. you're loading it from nib/storyboard) you have to override the archiving method `initWithCoder:`.

As suggested by the documentation you can create a routine for initialization and call it from both the designated initializer and the archiving method.

Comment: While that may be true if manually allocating view controllers, most of the time when dealing with storyboards or XIBs not loaded through your code you should be overriding `-initWithCoder:` instead.

Comment: Isn't it stupid to check latest docs every time you subclass something? Why not call init method on every type? I don't get this design decision...

Comment: @taras check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896896/always-use-a-designated-initializer

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thank's for your answer. The answer for linked question however is quite subjective, I completely disagree with it. Having designed initializer does not simplify anything, it complicates things, because you are just unable to subclass the damn thing without an internet connection...And that "Designed initializer" can call itself some UI methods, which is just WRONG. And there is no way to prevent this. Initing your ivars and then calling [super initWith...] is just wrong from OOP point of view

Answer (score 1):

It generally makes sense to use the designated initializer as a starting point, but if you are not sure this is always the one that will be used that won't make all that much sense.

Personally I therefore prefer to create a setup method which is called from any init-method I know is likely to be used at some stage. For ViewControllers I normally call the setup method from viewDidLoad instead (unless of course there's any state that's needed before this stage).